# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 Desktop Background After Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I know this is a small thing and a silly problem, but I recently upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 19.10 to 20.04, and it (predictably) changed my background. How can I get the default black and blue one from 19.10 back? Its not in the backgrounds folder and it matched my laptop so well...

Thanks!

Comment: Most probably the old ones were replaced by the new ones. Just google your favourite wallpaper buddy :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the wallpaper, but I would first check this folder `/usr/share/backgrounds`  or search like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20studio%2019.04%20default%20%20wallpaper&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiX18XymYLtAhWNMhQKHZoID0EQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=ubuntu%20studio%2019.04%20default%20%20wallpaper&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1D1LFjtTmCvUWgCcAB4AIABnQGIAdIQkgEEMC4xNpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=1-OvX9ePCI3lUJqRvIgE&bih=981&biw=1920).
Download the photo.
Then put the wallpaper in `/usr/share/backgrounds`